# Why is $PATH reversed?

Tags: zsh, path, macos

On my MacBook I use zsh, which I configured via a [`.zshenv`](https://github.com/baggiponte/dotfiles/blob/main/zsh/.zshenv) and a [`.zshrc`](https://github.com/baggiponte/dotfiles/blob/main/zsh/.zshrc).

If I add an `echo` statement at the end of the `.zshenv`, the `$PATH` variable looks like this:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
$HOME/.local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

However, after launching the terminal, the `$PATH` looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
$HOME/.local/bin
```

I added an `echo $PATH` statement at the very beginning of my `.zshrc` - which is sourced after the `.zshenv`, and indeed I verified that by the time the `.zshrc` is loaded, `$PATH` is changed to the second. **How do I prevent this?**

I suppose this has something to do with the files in `/etc`? For example, I noticed that there is an `/etc/paths` file with these contents:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Comment: What does your `.zshrc` file do to the path?

Comment: nothing! I just put the `echo $PATH` on top, before *anything* is executed, and the `$PATH` is still changed.

Comment: Could you possibly show your `.zshrc` file?

Comment: sure! the link was already above, but also [here](https://github.com/baggiponte/dotfiles/blob/main/zsh/.zshrc). I tried editing the `/etc/paths` file and as I expected the `$PATH` changed accordingly... but not during the `.zshenv` execution, but right before `.zshrc` is sourced.

Comment: oh okay if you scroll at the bottom of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388623/373894) you will see that `zsh` (on macOS?) reads the file in `/etc/` and then in your `$ZDOTDIR`. So it will read the `.zshenv` in `/etc/` and then in `$ZDOTDIR`. So the **system** `.zshenv` will be read before mine, than the **system** zprofile/zshrc are read before mine. That's how they override my `$PATH`

Comment: okay, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/432227/373894) is the proper answer to this in AskDifferent (SO for Apple). Will update the question body accordingly; mods might just delete the question altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this can be found in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/432227/373894) on AskDifferent, the Apple version of Unix&Linux StackExchange).

## Explanation

When zsh is sourced, files are read in the following order (from zsh official docs):

> Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden. [...] Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv. If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile. Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc. Finally, if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.

**In macOS's `/etc/zprofile`, a script is sourced that overrides the `$PATH` according to the contents of these files:**

- `/etc/paths`
- `/etc/paths.d`
- `/etc/manpaths`
- `/etc/manpaths.d`

## How to solve?

To solve this, you can:

1. Modify `/etc/paths` directly (not recommended)
2. Move the lines that modify `$PATH` to `.zprofile` or `.zshrc`.